# Sorting by Multiple Fields in List in Python

Tags: python, list, quicksort

As the title says i stucked with this kind of problem.
I have the unsorted `list` with `lists` (over 1000) inside.

`data = [['James', '4', '100'], ['Michelle', '6', '1000'], ['Robert', '2', '90'], ['Marques', '2', '90'], ['John', '4', '80'] ... ]`

I need to sort this array by such criteria and have priority:
Number at the [1] position of each list should be lowest at the start.
If we have the same number at [1] we compare number by lowest at the start at position [2]
And finally if for example `['Robert', '2', '90']`, `['Marques', '2', '90']` : we place the `'Marques'` first than `'Robert'` by alphabetical order.

Implementation should work via QuickSort in-place. How do I compare all of this - do I need to write 3 functions to compare different type of data or just need 1 function?

This is my 2 function to sort names and numbers. I just don't have an idea how to extract data - place it into function and get the sorted final list.

```
def partition(array, low, high):
    i = low - 1
    pivot = array[high]
    for j in range(low, high):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    array[i + 1], array[high] = array[high], array[i + 1]
    return i + 1


def quicksort_inplace(array, low=0, high=None):
    if high == None:
        high = len(array) - 1
    if low < high:
        p_idx = partition(array, low, high)
        quicksort_inplace(array, low, p_idx - 1)
        quicksort_inplace(array, p_idx + 1, high)


def sort_name(names):
    return names.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the sort() function.

Read more information on how it works here:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: As I said sorting of numbers should work with QuickSort method. Names though can be sorted with sort() function.